# Allocate memory to char pointer array as it is read in

Tags: c

I need to read white space separated words from stdin, then use an emalloc function to allocate memory for each word as it is read in.

I am finding this very confusing, here is what I have written so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    #define SIZE 100
    char* username[100]; 
    int i;
    int p;

    /* Read words into array */
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        username[i] = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char)); 
        scanf("%s",username[i]);
    }

    /* Print out array */
    for (p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
        printf("%s", username[p]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure whether I am reading words in correctly using scanf and I am pretty sure my memory allocation is not quite correct. Coming from Java, memory allocation is tricky to wrap my mind around. How come I do not include an & infront of username[i] in the scanf function?

Comment: We are not a tutoring/debugging/coding service. If you have a **specific** problem, state it and provide details.

Comment: Just don't add chatter. What you ask is shown in every beginners' C book. Your edit did not clarify anything.

Comment: @JamesBurton: "An array is actually just a pointer to the first element. " - **No**! An array is not a pointer! It is a different type. And the index-operator does not increment the pointer either. It is clearly not the same as `p++`.

Comment: @JamesBurton `sizeof` proves that arrays are not just pointers, and `username[1]` doesn't modify the variable like `username++` does.

Comment: Your code is fine. Read in only 3 words (change for loops). Hit enter after each word. After the 3rd word is entered your code prints the words properly. I see no real problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck I know ++ modifies the variable, what I wrote wasn't very well thought out (I've deleted my comment). I'm confused by you saying that an array isn't a pointer. I've always been taught it is so. In fact it even says it on tutorialspoint "An array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array.". For example *myArray == myArray[0]. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @JamesBurton you've been taught wrong, and tutorialspoint isn't doing you any favors. An identifier for an array *converts* to a temporary pointer-to-type (the type being the element type of the array) when used in any *expression context*. The array itself is *not* a pointer; it's an *array*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah ok thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @WhozCraig: "An identifier for an array converts to a temporary pointer-to-type (the type being the element type of the array) when used in any expression context." - That's clearly wrong. `sizeof` **is** an operator, i.e. "expression context", it takes an expression and `int a[4]; sizeof a;` does not decay the array to a pointer.

Comment: @JamesBurton: Don't rely on some obscure website. Before spreading something, check an authopritative resource. C is standardised as ISO9899 (ccurrent and only valid version: from 2011), read it (it is not that problematic once one gets used to it). See the tag-wiki for more.

Comment: @Olaf You say that as if you're not  aware that operator `sizeof` specifically calls out array types as operands per C9899 §6.5.3.4 p3, "When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array." Yet we both know that you *are* aware that is the case. `sizeof` has rules as an operator, one of which is how to treat array types or expressions. So I'm not sure what the point is.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I explicitly cited what the problem is with your comment.  `sizeof` clearly works on the type of the expression of its operand, not the name. It could be something like `int (*a)[2]; sizeof *a;` as well, which is an expression. Hence your statement about "expression context" is missleading, if not wrong as stated (I very well know you know about arrays in C).

Comment: @Olaf I wasn't relying on the website. I was going off what I've been taught from University, if I'm at fault for presuming that was correct then I might as well drop out. I only got the website from a quick search to double check after I was told I was incorrect.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for clarifying your comment. I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine with only a few problems:

> 1. You should be free'ing the memory your array of pointers point to.
> 2. The use of scanf() is dangerous as a buffer overflow could occur.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    #define SIZE 100
    char* username[100]; 
    char *nl;

    int i;
    int p;

    /* Read words into array */
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        username[i] = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char)); 
        printf("Enter word %d:", i+1);
        fgets( username[i], SIZE, stdin );
        // Remove newline
        if ((nl = strchr(username[i], '\n')))
        {
            *nl = '\0';
        }
    }

    /* Print out array */
    for (p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
        printf("[%s]\n", username[p]);
        free( username[p] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
~/src/svn/misc > ./a.out 
Enter word 1:One
Enter word 2:Two
Enter word 3:Three
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: @eZ_Harry Glad I could help out.